# Find a key associated with a value using indexing

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, indexing

I have a dictionary of where the keys are cities and the values are lists of rent values. What I wanted to do is return the lowest average rent and the city associated with it. I am very new to python so I was hoping for a solution that avoided import and rather for loops or indexing.

```
{'Houston': [1400.0, 860.0, 1498.0], 'Los Angeles': [1560.0, 1350.0, 600.0, 940.0], 'New York': [873.0, 11510.0, 1021.0]}
```

Comment: Can you find the average of a list of numbers? Can you find the average? Think in terms of little pieces, then put them together.

Comment: @Chris yea I was able to find the lowest average I just can't figure out how to return both the city and the lowest average

Answer (score 1):

Finding the average for each:

```
data = {
  'Houston': [1400.0, 860.0, 1498.0], 
  'Los Angeles': [1560.0, 1350.0, 600.0, 940.0], 
  'New York': [873.0, 11510.0, 1021.0]
}


for city, rents in data.items():
    print(f"{city}: Avg rent: ${sum(rents) / len(rents) : 0.2f}")
```

We can get these values in a list with a comprehension.

```
[sum(rents) / len(rents) for city, rents in data.items()]
```

We can convert this list comprehension to a generator expression and pass it to `min` to find the smallest average rent.

```
min(sum(rents) / len(rents) for city, rents in data.items())
```

Now, we know the minimum average rent. We need to find any cities where that is the average rent. We can use a dictionary comprehension for that.

```
>>> def avg(vals): return sum(vals) / len(vals)
... 
>>> min_avg = min(avg(rents) for _, rents in data.items())
>>> {city: rents for city, rents in data.items() if avg(rents) == min_avg}
{'Los Angeles': [1560.0, 1350.0, 600.0, 940.0]}
>>>
```